# org.omg.CORBA.TRANSACTION_ROLLEDBACK: vmcid: 0x0 minor code: 0 completed: No

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-content-engine, filenet-process-engine, filenet-cpe

i am using Filenet 5.2.1 on Websphere 8.5.5.13
and when trying to connect to filenet connection point to retrieve work items as follows :

```
workObject = (VWWorkObject) rosterElement.fetchWorkObject(false, false);
```

I get the following exception:

```
org.omg.CORBA.TRANSACTION_ROLLEDBACK:   vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
    at filenet.pe.ejb.client.PEEJBSession.executeRPC(PEEJBSession.java:1028)
    at filenet.pe.ejb.client.PEEJBSession.getWorkElementFields(PEEJBSession.java:1880)
    at filenet.vw.api.VWWorkElement.fetchFields(VWWorkElement.java:118)
    at filenet.vw.api.VWRosterElement.fetchWorkObject(VWRosterElement.java:154)
    at com.test.myapp.PublicInbox.inboxQueue(PublicInbox.java:320)
    at com.test.myapp.PublicInbox.onload(PublicInbox.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4616.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:328)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:341)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstPropertySuffix.invoke(AstPropertySuffix.java:58)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:96)
    at org.jboss.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(Unknown Source)
    at org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener.processAction(DialogActionListener.java:45)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewAction.broadcast(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.PostprocessorFilter.doFilter(PostprocessorFilter.java:38)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.ContainerBasedFilter.doFilter(ContainerBasedFilter.java:218)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.PreprocessorFilter.doFilter(PreprocessorFilter.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.SecurityPluginFilter.doFilter(SecurityPluginFilter.java:202)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.ThreadLocalCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalCleanupFilter.java:50)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at gov.mci.web.filter.CoordinatorSecurityFilter.doFilter(CoordinatorSecurityFilter.java:208)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.dataserve.common.CompatibleFilter.doFilter(CompatibleFilter.java:53)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4028)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1016)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.TRANSACTION_ROLLEDBACK:   vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
    at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTS.TxClientInterceptor.send_request(TxClientInterceptor.java:497)
    at com.ibm.rmi.pi.InterceptorManager.invokeInterceptor(InterceptorManager.java:574)
    at com.ibm.rmi.pi.InterceptorManager.iterateClientInterceptors(InterceptorManager.java:419)
    at com.ibm.rmi.pi.InterceptorManager.iterateSendRequest(InterceptorManager.java:640)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ClientRequestImpl.<init>(ClientRequestImpl.java:180)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl$1.run(GIOPImpl.java:195)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:594)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.createRequest(GIOPImpl.java:192)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate._createRequest_WLM(ClientDelegate.java:1841)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1047)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1129)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1514)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1028)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1480)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1658)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1436)
    at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._request(ObjectImpl.java:458)
    at filenet.vw.server.rpc._IPESendAPIRPCRemote_Stub.sendCommandBytes(_IPESendAPIRPCRemote_Stub.java)
    at filenet.pe.ejb.client.PESendAPIRPCProxy.ejbInvokeAsBytes(PESendAPIRPCProxy.java:129)
    at filenet.pe.ejb.client.PESendAPIRPCProxy.ejbInvoke(PESendAPIRPCProxy.java:107)
    at filenet.pe.ejb.client.PERPCProxyBase.privateInvokeRPC(PERPCProxyBase.java:475)
    at filenet.pe.ejb.client.PERPCProxyBase.access$000(PERPCProxyBase.java:96)
    at filenet.pe.ejb.client.PERPCProxyBase$EJBExecuteAction.run(PERPCProxyBase.java:134)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:686)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:569)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:196)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:153)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor55.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.util.J2EEUtilWS.doAs(J2EEUtilWS.java:239)
    at com.filenet.api.util.UserContext.doAs(UserContext.java:142)
    at filenet.pe.ejb.client.PERPCProxyBase.invokeRPC(PERPCProxyBase.java:519)
    at filenet.pe.ejb.client.PEEJBSession.executeRPC(PEEJBSession.java:883)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check to ensure your CORBA destination is available.  I am unsure if there are any additional connections being used and this is just one of them, but it seems like it is bailing out immediately on calling it (`filenet.pe.ejb.client.PEEJBSession.executeRPC`).  Additionally, although it seems slightly different, it may be worth your while to ensure you are on filenet > 5.2.1.7-P8CPE-IF005 (You indicated 5.2.1, but not the fourth digit release you are using).  It seems there was an error related to executeRPC patched in that version.  See information [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/PJ45088).